# How to generate missing values of three missing types(i.e. MCAR, MAR and MNAR) altogether using Python?

Tags: python, missing-data

I have a complete dataset and now I want to generate missing values of three missing types(i.e. MCAR, MAR and MNAR) altogether.

1. If I generate each type of missing values one by one, will the ultimate missing rate in the dataset be the sum of the three?
2. Is there any combined approach to introduce 3 types of missing, instead of generate each type separetely?

Thansk a looooooooooooooooot!!!

Tried approach on this weibsite: https://rmisstastic.netlify.app/how-to/python/generate_html/how%20to%20generate%20missing%20values.

```py
    # Set fixed random seed
    np.random.seed(0)

    # Introduce missing
    incop_df = produce_na(frame, p_miss=p[0], mecha="MCAR")
    incop_df = produce_na(incop_df, p_miss=p[1], mecha="MAR")
    incop_df = produce_na(incop_df, p_miss=p[2], mecha="MNAR")
```

where p is a list containing the missing rate of three types respectively.

My dataset is a time series DataFrame, the head of which is posted below.

[Head of my original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcmJF.png)

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code, collected dataset, and collection protocol that you are working with.

Comment: The motivation behind MCAR / MAR / MNAR is to quantify how "observables" differ from "the real world". Not sure what your `produce_na()` is, but rolling your own random numbers isn't likely to be helpful. Here's an example. We wish to understand diet in a population of a million people. We spend money to administer a questionnaire instrument to a subset of them, asking "how many grams of <certain ingredient> did you consume in the last 30 days?". But we administered it only in English, so some folks who speak other languages did not respond. Language correlates with cuisine, so we have bias.

Comment: Thanks a lot JH! My overall target is to do imputation on mulyiple missing types. Hence the first step in my opinion is to introduce artificial missing values of different types. The function `produce_na()` is largely based on the code of [BorisMuzellc](https://github.com/BorisMuzellec/MissingDataOT), which takes the parameter of missing rate and type. Therefore, how can I generate artificial missing values without changing its original distribution? Or, is my approach above acceptable? Really appreciate it.